# How do I test my application's response to malformed URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In the development and testing environment, we don't really see any malformed URLs, but in the real world, applications are often accessed by poorly-written crawlers, people trying SQL injection attacks, etc. requesting malformed URLs from the application (unescaped punctuation, etc.).

I found that my site being requested from a malformed URL was tickling a bug, so I went to fix the bug and write tests for it.  Here is an example of a test:

```
  scenario "with a garbage URL" do
    visit "/<<"

    # my actual expectation is irrelevant to this question
    expect(some_result).to have_happened
  end
```

The problem here is that `visit "/<<"` throws an exception *in the testing tool*, and my application never gets hit, because Capybara will refuse to visit a malformed URL.

So, what is the best way to test whether my application is replying appropriately to malformed URLs, invalid query strings, etc. that the testing tool won't generate?

Answer (score 0):

In testing, the part of the URL that is malformed that gets sent to your application is the part after the host name. If you want that part of the URL to be malformed, you still need to provide an URL that your tool can parse. So that means including the scheme and hostname, so it is clear you are just passing a malformed path.

Instead of

```
visit "/<<"
```

use

```
visit "http://testing.example.com/<<"
```

Comment: Even with the full URL specified, capybara itself, not my application, is the one that throws the exception.  My application is never seeing it.

Comment: You need to better define what you mean by "malformed URL". If the URL does not specify a valid host or scheme, then it will not be usable, but such an URL will also not be making it to your application. The `path` component can include almost anything, so it should not be a problem. If you want to send a request that is not a valid HTTP request, then you need to use something like [`TCPSocket`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html) to create a socket and send whatever data you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be writing this test as a request spec (without Capybara) rather than a feature/system spec - see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec

Comment: Even in a request spec, it's the testing tool itself that throws the URI::InvalidURIError, so my application never gets the chance to see it.